# CSS problems with DIV placement

Tags: css, html

I've got a couple of DIV's within a containing DIV . I want them to sit next each other horizontally but no matter what I do they stay on the vertical.

code :

```
<style>

#entrycontainer {
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
}
#entry {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
</style>

      <div id="entrycontainer" >

          <div id="entry" >
          <h1>PHP File Upload/Browser</h1>
          <img src="img/projectimg/fileupimg.png" />
          <p>PHP MySQL CSS</p>
          </div>

          <div id="entry"  >
          <h1>PHP File Upload/Browser</h1>
          <img src="img/projectimg/fileupimg.png" />
          <p>PHP MySQL CSS</p>
          </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `float:left;` to you entry class should look like this also of note you should change like I did for you in the code the #entry to .entry and change them to reference a class.  the correct use of class is anytime more than one element is styled on the same page it should be set as a class.

```
<style type="text/css">

#entrycontainer {
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
}
.entry {
    float: left;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}
</style>

      <div id="entrycontainer" >

          <div class="entry" >
          <h1>PHP File Upload/Browser</h1>
          <img src="img/projectimg/fileupimg.png" />
          <p>PHP MySQL CSS</p>
          </div>

          <div class="entry"  >
          <h1>PHP File Upload/Browser</h1>
          <img src="img/projectimg/fileupimg.png" />
          <p>PHP MySQL CSS</p>
          </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements with the same `id`. The `id` property is *unique*, which means that it is used to reference a *single* element. If you want to group elements together, use `class`, as it can be used multiple times.

As for the fix, `float: left` the elements. `div` elements are `block`s, so they don't stay inline. Also notice my `overflow: auto` statement in the parent element. That is used to account for the `float`s.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g9bgV/1/**

Answer (score 0):

You can't (or shouldn't) have two divs with the same ID; for one thing. Secondly, divs are block elements which mean that unless you change the behavior with styling, they will always appear on a new line.

Change your CSS to be like this:

```
.entry {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
```

And change your HTML to be like this:

```
      <div id="1" class="entry" >
      <h1>PHP File Upload/Browser</h1>
      <img src="img/projectimg/fileupimg.png" />
      <p>PHP MySQL CSS</p>
      </div>

      <div id="2" class="entry"  >
      <h1>PHP File Upload/Browser</h1>
      <img src="img/projectimg/fileupimg.png" />
      <p>PHP MySQL CSS</p>
      </div>
```

That should be enough to get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to float the internal divs.
2. You also need to use a class, since an `id` should be unique on a page.

   .entry{
              float: left;
              width: 200px;
              height: 100px;
         }

Answer (score 0):

divs are block-level elements, meaning they will always be placed below the previous content (as opposed to inline elements, like span)

- you could add float:left; to both blocks
- or use display:table on the container, and display:table-cell on the inside blocks